# Exporting to archive in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, export, project

I am trying to export a project in eclipse to an archive file and then zip it. However when the file is zipped it is not including a .jpg image that is located in my src folder. Why is the image not being included in the .zip? It is needed to run my project otherwise it will throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure while you 're exporting the project , to check the export files and resources , not only the java classes

Comment: you are welcome , so you can up vote  if the answer was useful , or Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)

Answer (score 0):

When you export to an archive, Eclipse will prompt you for what files you actually want to include.  Checking everything in your project will achieve what you want.

However, if all you need is a .zip file, it might be easier to simply archive the entire project directory using some archiving utility.